# Send `PUT` and `DELETE` request using CURL

Tags: php, curl

Is it possible to send `PUT` and `DELETE` request using `curl`. As we send `POST` and `GET` request in `curl`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");             
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

How to send `PUT` and `DELETE` request.

Comment: This reads as if you did not bother taking a look into the documentation? _Why not?_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` option like so:

```
curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
```

Here, `$curlObject` is the result obtained from `curl_init`.

This is all detailed on the relevant API reference page:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Similar for PUT curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

Answer (score -1):

The DELETE request method asks the server to delete the resource specified in the Request-URI.

```
$url = yourwebsite.com/resource/delete/json?id=1    
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

Put request is similar to the post request. See the below example or check https://www.tutorialspoint.com/send-a-curl-delete-request-with-example

```
$data = ["name" => 'test', "Address" => 'Canada'];
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```